# Executing a thread inside AsyncTask's doInBackground()

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have several `AsyncTask`s doing network operations. I was recently asked to add, after each of these operations, another network call that invokes a remote service sending some statistics. I'd like this statistics call not to delay 'main' network calls, and so I was thinking of executing them in a thread created and started inside the `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()`. This thread would most probably end after the `doInBackground()` and possibly the whole `AsyncTask` has ended. I tried this and it works, but I was wondering if there are side effects, such as memory leaks or similar?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try starting a second AsyncTask in the first AsyncTasks 'onPostExecute' Method.
For me this worked without any issues.

Comment: Mmmh that would require some effort to make the data I need to send for statistics available in the `onPostExecute()` too... Do you see any problem with my approach which, by the way, is working?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start thread in `doInBackground` method, you can start it in `onProgressUpdate()` method

Example:

```
protected class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Void> {

        public static final int START_THREAD = -1;
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            if(values[0] == START_THREAD){
                startThread();
            }
        }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        publishProgress(START_THREAD);
        return null;
    }
}
```