# Creating another AsyncTask inside of doInBackground

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I recently looked through SO to find the answer [to the same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607399/executing-a-thread-inside-asynctasks-doinbackground), but there was not an answer directed at the question in regards to the risk of doing so.  But basically I want to run another `AsyncTask` inside the `doInBackground()` method of another `AsyncTask`.  Is this a bad approach and/or does it leave any potential side effects?

I know that running it in the `onPostExecute()` works and so far from past experiences I have not had any issues due to the fact that `onPostExecute()` runs back on the main thread which started a `AsyncTask` to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the API docs:

> •The task instance must be created on the UI thread.

doInBackground() runs on the background thread. So you cannot create and run another asynctask from doInBackground().

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask. Have a look at the topic under **threading rules.**

When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps: (Straight from the doc)

> 1.onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance
> by showing a progress bar in the user interface.
>
> 2.**doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread** immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used
> to perform background computation that can take a long time. The
> parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
> result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
> passed back to the last step. This step can also use
> publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress.
> These values are published on the UI thread, in the
> onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
>
> 3.onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
> undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
> user interface while the background computation is still executing.
> For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
> a text field.
>
> 4.onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is
> passed to this step as a parameter.

When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

**If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.**

**Update 05-04-2023**

AsyncTask is no more used in the android world for async stuff. Consider using Coroutines. Suggest to switch to coroutines ASAP

https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines?gclid=Cj0KCQjwla-hBhD7ARIsAM9tQKuy9BV88avgYYrrwkcCHJ1zktoctbOrdrWavXT0NTDktIfPdfb8Q-4aAqXIEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

The codelab sample is availabe at https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines#0

Comment: Very nice and thorough response along with multiple alternatives. Thanks once again Raghunandan

Comment: +1 for such a comprehensive answer. I was interested to read `The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.` (from the docs) - do you know what is done automatically?

Comment: @ David Caunt check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978924/what-is-the-difference-between-loading-and-creating-asynctask-on-the-ui-thread.

Comment: @Nate check the threading rules http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. Class loading and execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread. I think its the same link i have posted in the answer and i merely quoted it from docs

Comment: @Nate could you edit that part. i guess the phrase loading is misleading

Comment: @Nate Thank you. You are right about class loading i deleted the comment that said Loaded means ... must be spawned.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask(), with the exception of the Honeycomb releases, execute serially.  So, no, you cannot execute another AsyncTask() from within doInBackground() -- I guess I should say that I've never tried it, but it's highly unlikely you're going to achieve the desired affect.

I asked about AsyncTask() execution during one of the Google Office Hours.  Straight from their mouths when asked, "Why did it change from serial to parallel and back to serial execution?"; "Because it broke a lot of stuff."

Comment: This isn't entirely true. The execute method executes the task on the default executor, which happens to be a single thread (serial) executor since Honeycomb, as you say. But you can execute tasks on your own executor with [executeOnExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...)). This works well for tasks which can safely be performed in parallel.

Comment: @DavidCaunt 100% true.  +1 Was just trying to keep it simple :)