# Multiple HTTP requests in one AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post, http-get

So I have an app that will first make a `HTTPPOST` request to validate login details. 
If the login details are correct it should then further make another two `HTTPGET` requests otherwise do nothing.

I know how to right the code to have this done with 3 `AsyncTask`s but is there a way to do it from one ? Or is 3 seperate classes correct, coding style wise ?

If not can someone point me in the right direction/give me an exampl of how it would be done in one seeing as I have to evaluate the results of the first `HTTPPOST` which I do in `OnPostExecute` and then have another `HTTPGET`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657424/creating-another-asynctask-inside-of-doinbackground/15657500#15657500 check this if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Google Volley. It's a great and simple library for networking and remote image loading.

Volley "hides" the whole threading issue in its core, all you have to do is issue a request. No need to manage AsyncTasks.

[Check it out.](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728)