# Android getting a result from an asynctask from within and asynctask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have two AsyncTasks running and the async task that is waiting for the result is just not getting the correct result.

I have a network class that runs like so:

```
public ArrayList<User> searchForFriends(String activeHash, TelephoneNumber telephone)
{
    Object[] obj = {activeHash, telephone};
    try
    {
        return new SearchForFriendsTelephone().execute(obj).get(Constants.TIMEOUT_TIME, Constants.TIMEOUT_UNIT);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

private class SearchForFriendsTelephone extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, ArrayList<User>>
{
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<User> doInBackground(Object... searchTelephone)
    {
        if (config.getNetworkVersion() == config.NETWORK_PROTOCOL_VERSION_1)
        {
            TelephoneNumber tel = (TelephoneNumber) searchTelephone[1];
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(NetworkConfig.POST_ACTIVE_HASH, (String) searchTelephone[0]));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(NetworkConfig.POST_MOBILE_NUMBER_COUNTRY_CODE, tel.getCountryCode()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(NetworkConfig.POST_MOBILE_NUMBER_RAW, tel.getNumberRaw()));
            ServerCommunication csc = new ServerCommunication();
            JSONObject jsonFoundFriends = csc.postToServer(config.getBaseUrl() + URL_FRIEND_SEARCH_MOBILE, params);
            if (jsonFoundFriends == null || csc.networkError())
            {
                FriendNetworkCommunication.this.networkError = csc.getNetworkError();
                return null;
            }
            return _processSearchFriends(jsonFoundFriends);
        }
        FriendNetworkCommunication.this.networkError = new NetworkError(NetworkLanguage.UNABLE_TO_PROCESS);
        return null;
    }
```

Anyway this works fine with no issues and pulls back the user/s. I know this as I tried the following code in the main ui thread and it populates a view just fine. When I call this code from another AsyncTask. I get a timeout error.

Code to all the searchForFriends code:

```
private class CompareNumbers extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<NameAndNumber>, Integer, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<NameAndNumber>... params)
    {
        for (NameAndNumber nameNumber : params[0])
        {
            try
            {
                FriendNetworkCommunication fnc = new FriendNetworkCommunication();
                ArrayList<User> users = fnc.searchForFriends(CurrentUser.getInstance().getUserActiveHash(), new TelephoneNumber(String.valueOf(nameNumber.getNumber().getNationalNumber()), String.valueOf(nameNumber.getNumber().getCountryCode())));
                if (users != null && users.size() == 1)
                {
                    User u = users.get(0);
                    String[] s = nameNumber.getName().split(" ");
                    u.setFirstName(s[0]);
                    u.setLastName(s[1]);
                    ((ArrayAdapter<User>) ((ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.friend_add_fragment_search_cont_list)).getAdapter()).add(u);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ((ArrayAdapter<User>) ((ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.friend_add_fragment_search_cont_list)).getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        return null;
    }
 }
```

Can I not run an asynctask that waits on another?

NOTE: This is all running in a fragment if this makes any difference?

NOTE2: The first Asynctask runs a network call and has to be run asynchronously and so I wanted it to be like this so if I wanted I could run it anywhere synchronously

Comment: Could you please also show your second AsyncTask and how it calls the first one?

Comment: A reason for using AsyncTasks is so you don't have to wait. If one task depends on data from another, then it shouldn't be initiated until that other one is complete.

Comment: Look at updated post

Comment: The first Asynctask runs a network call and has to be run asynchronously and so I wanted it to be like this so if I wanted  I could run it anywhere synchronously

Comment: I don't see the point in calling another `AsyncTask` in the `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask`. If you want the rest of the code from the first `AsyncTask` to execute only after the second `AsyncTask` has finished, then why use a second `AsyncTask`?

Comment: @shyam The reason is that sometimes I will make this call in a synchronous mannor and setting a new async task is a real pain in the ass so if it already runs in an AsyncTask then I save myself a lot of trouble

Answer (score 1):

try giving the .execute() of the second async task in the  onpostexecute() of the first async task.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question and this is not possible.

A full answer can be found here:

[Creating another AsyncTask inside of doInBackground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657424/creating-another-asynctask-inside-of-doinbackground)