# How to wait for intent service to finish - When the intent service is started from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

Here is my scenario:

I have a login form which has a member key field, once the user enters this key I communicate with server to authenticate. There are two more fields namely key and type I add up these in a JSON object and send that across to the server.

Now due to a request I also have to send across the GCM token along with this login information in one call. On submit button click I start the following async task

My do in Background method looks like this:

```
  @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            if (checkPlayServices()) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, GcmRegistrationIntentService.class);
                   startService(intent);
            }
/***// I want to wait here and fetch the GCM token value//***/

            try {
                JSONObject jObj;
                jObj = new JSONObject();

                jObj.put("aes_key", UtilityClass.getencryptkey());
                jObj.put("client_id", key);
                jObj.put("type", "Android");
                // jObj.put("device_token", ); <--- Need to wait for this value


                System.out.println(jObj);
                String authenticateResp = authenticate(jObj);
                System.out.println("Response is: " + authenticateResp);

                JSONObject jResp = new JSONObject(authenticateResp);
                String success = jResp.getString("success");


                if (success.equalsIgnoreCase("True")) {

                    sessionManager.createLoginSession(key);
                    return "granted";

                } else {
                    return jResp.getString("msg");

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Something went wrong, we are working to fix this, please try again after sometime";
            }
        }

        public String authenticate(JSONObject jObject) {
            return UniversalNetworkConnection.postJSONObject(getResources().getString(R.string.authentication_url), jObject);
        }
```

So first I start with starting the intent service - which has a registered local broadcast determining that the service has finished, I get the handler to this in onCreate of the particular activity.

```
 mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("Login Act", "GCM done");
            }
        };
```

I want to wait in the middle of the doInBackground till I receive the local broadcast from my intent service. So that I can add up the value to my JSON object. It is necessary  for me to do this in an Async task because I have to update the UI with relevant messages of authentication success or false. Otherwise I could have migrated all my logic to the intent service - which would be a lot couples and which is not a good design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move all your logic to `onReceive` of that broadcast receiver. Declare that receiver as an inner class of your activity and then you can manipulate UI within it.

So the steps after user click are:

- Start that Intent Service.
- Send an broad cast in that service when you are done.
- Send your JSON object in `onReceive` method.

**Note:** if you want to send that JSON in background thread, you could simply define an thread inside `onReceive` and do the work.

Comment: I am of the opinion that this would be the best solution, however it means refactoring a lot of code and keeping track of UI messages would be come tedious. However I still am of the opinion that I will go with this way

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do another asynchronous task inside doInBackground. This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15657500/4676276

What you can do is, start the smaller async task first then wait for it to finish then start the main async on the `onPostExecute` of the first task.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Check for the key and wait

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, GcmRegistrationIntentService.class);
               startService(intent);
        }
        /***// I want to wait here and fetch the GCM token value//***/

        while(key==null||key.length()==0){

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

       }

       try {
            JSONObject jObj;
            jObj = new JSONObject();

            jObj.put("aes_key", UtilityClass.getencryptkey());
            jObj.put("client_id", key);
            jObj.put("type", "Android");
       /**********************/

   }
```